# Sending CSRF Tokens via Postman

Tags: django, post, get, csrf, postman

I'm trying to test my web server's login with Postman. First, I send a GET request to my login url, and I get a CSRF token as a cookie. Then, I make a POST request to that login page, with my username, password, and CSRF token.

My problem is, when I do this in Postman, I get a 403 forbidden error when I try to make that POST request to login. I'm copying the CSRF token received and putting it as one of the POST parameters, and I'm using a valid username and password. Is there anything I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Do you set a session `csrfmiddlewaretoken ` cookie?

Comment: After successful login there is no need to supply username and password to the request, you need only the CSRF token since you already authenticated.

Answer (score 18):

You need to set it as a **header** in the request, **not in the body**. `X-CSRFToken` is the key and the value is CSRF token from the cookie. This will work if you are using an API framework like `Tastypie` or `Django Rest Framework`.

If you are authenticating without an API layer you would need to actually attach the cookie or create one with the CSRF token. [This post](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/working_with_cookies) explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the **Postman Interceptor** Extension on GoogleChrome. It worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

Works for me :

Set in Postman Header :

KEY : Authorization

Value : Token "Your token"